# Why does JAAS' Krb5LoginModule require access to the domain controller?

Tags: java, authentication, alfresco, kerberos, jaas

From my understanding of Kerberos, the protocol is meant to eliminate the need of the Kerberized service being accessed and the KDC to have any form of communication. This hypothesis is confirmed [here](http://www.kerberos.org/software/tutorial.html) in the first paragraph of chapter 4:

> At this point, it is important to underline that an application server
>   never communicates directly with the Key Distribution Center: the
>   service tickets, even if packeted by TGS, reach the service only
>   through the client wishing to access them.

Now I'm working with a Java Kerberos service, specifically Alfresco, which is implemented using JAAS and its' Krb5LoginModule. However, delving into the source code for that LoginModule, it looks like it behaves like a client more than a service. It can be configured to use a ticket cache, it can access the TGS, and one of the first things it does when asked to authenticate, is send an `AS_REQ` request, which is the first step performed by the client in Kerberos authentication (as shown in that fourth chapter). What it does not seem to do, is decrypt the clients' authenticator using the service secret key, [source](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/security/auth/module/Krb5LoginModule.java).

It looks like JAAS Kerberos services handle authentication by just taking the credentials/keys the client provides, and sending them to the KDC to fetch a TGT. If that works, then the credentials must've been OK. But this way, JAAS requires access to the KDC itself. Does JAAS' Kerberos 5 implementation blatantly fail to actually follow the protocol here? Oracle does seem to advertise JAAS and its' Kerberos support to be used for services to authenticate their users.

Comment: Just being curious: does Alfresco use the client's credentials to connect to a third-party service, provided the ticket(s) is/are forwardable/proxiable/etc?

Comment: From what I've seen, no. It justs retrieves a TGT. But it's a good point; if Alfresco wanted to connect to another service on the user's behalf seemlessly, this would be a way to do that. I can't really think of a use case though. Alfresco doesn't often need to behave like a client.